# JavaScript Calculator equal button returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, undefined, project, calculator, addeventlistener

I'm working on a simple JavaScript calculator. Everything seems fine and other buttons works as expected except for the equal button which returns an "undefined" when it is clicked. On clicking the equal button, "if" the value of the screen is empty, I want the value of the screen to be set to an empty string, else, the new screen.value should be the result of an eval();
I've gone over the code several times and can't find what the problem is. Pls help. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calculator.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <form>
            <input type="text" class="screen" placeholder="0" value="";>
        </form>

        <div class="buttons">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-yellow" data-num="*">*</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-yellow" data-num="/">/</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-yellow" data-num="-">-</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-yellow" data-num="+">+</button>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num="9">9</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num="8">8</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num="7">7</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num="6">6</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num="5">5</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num="4">4</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num="3">3</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num="2">2</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num="1">1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num="0">0</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num=".">.</button>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-equal">=</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-clear">C</button>
            
        </div>


    </div>
        

<script type="text/javascript" src="calculator.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

JAVASCRIPT CODE HERE

(function(){

    let screen = document.querySelector(".screen");
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
    let equal = document.querySelector(".btn-equal");
    let clear = document.querySelector(".btn-clear");

    buttons.forEach(function(button) {
        button.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            let value = e.target.dataset.num;
            screen.value += value;
        })
    });
    
    equal.addEventListener("click", function(e){
       if (screen.value === "") {
          screen.value = "";
        } else{
            let answer = eval(screen.value); 
            screen.value = answer;
        } 
    })

    clear.addEventListener("click", function(){
        screen.value = "";
    })


})();
```

Comment: Use a debugger. Step through your click handlers. You'll notice something funny when you click the `=` button.

Comment: the issue is not in the equal button itself - check out the previous `buttons.forEach` and I think you'll find it

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks alot Sir. I did that and i noticed that the "something funny" is in this line of the code; `let answer = eval(screen.value); ` but i really don't know how to fix that as i can't tell what the exact problem is with that line of code.

Comment: I would recommend NOT using **eval** it is a known security hole. But getting rid of it, will require additional programming of understanding if statements and even switches and something like parseFloat to convert the strings to a number.

Comment: You should have noticed something even before you got to the `let answer = eval(screen.value)`. `screen.value` got modified. And if you set a breakpoint on *all* of the click handlers, you'll see why.

Answer (score 2):

The issue because you give the "=" button a ".btn" class, which has the 'click' event listener, and because the "=" button doesn't have attribute data-num, the input will be concatenate with undefined, so any calculation you will do will be end with "undefined" which give Syntax error.

So just removing "btn" class from "=" button will solve the issue.

This works, please check.

```js
(function(){

    let screen = document.querySelector(".screen");
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
    let equal = document.querySelector(".btn-equal");
    let clear = document.querySelector(".btn-clear");

    buttons.forEach(function(button) {
        button.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            let value = e.target.dataset.num;
            console.log(value)
            screen.value += value;
        })
    });
    
    equal.addEventListener("click", function(e){
       if (screen.value === "") {
          screen.value = "";
        } else{
            console.log(screen.value)
            let answer = eval(screen.value);
            screen.value = answer;
        } 
    })

    clear.addEventListener("click", function(){
        screen.value = "";
    })


})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calculator.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <form>
            <input type="text" class="screen" placeholder="0" value="";>
        </form>

        <div class="buttons">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-yellow" data-num="*">*</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-yellow" data-num="/">/</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-yellow" data-num="-">-</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-yellow" data-num="+">+</button>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num="9">9</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num="8">8</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num="7">7</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num="6">6</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num="5">5</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num="4">4</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num="3">3</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num="2">2</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num="1">1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num="0">0</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-grey" data-num=".">.</button>

            <button type="button" class="btn-equal">=</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-clear">C</button>
            
        </div>


    </div>
        


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much sir. I can now sleep on the bed